# Does .NET CLR precalculate property values?

Tags: c#, .net

When I run C# code through the debugger, calculated property values always seem to be displayed when I inspect an object.

e.g.

[image]

I am wondering if this is only done in the debugger, or if .Net does this as an optimization and can detect when a property changes, because this would affect how I use and access such properties to avoid performing calculations multiple times.

I have never seen it *not* display the value in the debugger even with complex calculations.

Comment: Are you saying that a breakpoint placed immediately before that line will show the calculated value of Val before that line is executed?

Comment: I guess it's done in the debugger to calculate and display property values when you inspect it. Maybe you could add some simple logging to the getter and setter of a property to get to know when things are accessed.

Comment: …also, are `x` and `y.z` constants?

Comment: The execution engine doesn't even know about properties; it just sees them as the constituent methods and backing field. While the assembly metadata does group these methods and fields into properties, that's only for reflection and use by other compilers referencing the code, not the normal runtime process.

Comment: The debugger takes control of *everything* in the application, so it knows when something is modified or not. Even Release builds behave differently when run under the debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The debugger is calling `.ToString()` on all the objects.  Whatever code is implemented in that function for each object is executed, which may mean it looks like the debugger has some insider information, but it really doesn't.

You can confirm this by writing your own `.ToString()` function in a class and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The value of your auto-property will be computed *when something calls the getter*. It just so happens that the debugger will call the getter to *display* the property value, which is what you are seeing.

> I am wondering if ... .Net does this as an optimization and can detect when a property changes, because this would affect how I use and access such properties to avoid performing calculations multiple times.

There is no built-in property value caching. Since the get method will be executed whenever you "get" the property, the calculation will be executed every time. If you want to cache the value, you could add a backing field, but *you'll* need to detect if/when to recalculate the value. One way would be to add logic to the setter of `Value` to either invalidate the cache or recompute the dependent properties (like `MessageCode`) at that time.

My opinion is that such a simple calculation is safe to run millions of times rather then adding the overhead of change detection.

Comment: I am thinking more of cases where you have a calculated value like `Size` or `Checksum`... it could be tempting to do these as get-only properties but perhaps bes-practices say these should be implemented as methods?

Comment: Well, a get-only property _is_ just a method. That method _could_ include a backing field and smart caching, but it's not there automatically.

Comment: Yes but would a user reasonably expect reading a property should have no appreciable cost?

Comment: Sure, and I would say that a simple calculation like you have (a bit shift, an AND and a subtraction) has no appreciable cost. _If_ that calculation accounts for a significant amount of time in your app overall, _then_ you can look at doing some caching.

Comment: Good hint @DStanley. Reminds me of this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms229054(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN It's from 2013 but the concepts should be kind of timeless. Basically it says that properties should only be used if they provide a kind of basic access to stored data. They can contain some basic logic but they shouldn't add complexity to the system. In other cases use methods.

Comment: Quote from that article: "By implementing Employees as a method, you indicate to developers that this action is more computationally expensive than accessing a field. Developers are more likely to call a method once and cache the results of the method call to perform their processing."

Comment: So, @Mr.Boy, if you have performance concerns think about switching from property getters to methods as this is a strong indication that methods are more appropriate here. Of course, the mere technical question isn't answered by this.